# Json - Complete records with duplicate data, or normalized

Tags: javascript, json, performance

This is a very general question but as a beginner I would appreciate if I could pick your brains a bit.

I am in the process of separating data extraction and presentation in a project of mine and wanted to get some feedback on how do this in the best way.

At the moment the data is "normalized" (~5MB) to avoid data duplication, but I am considering going the other direction to make it easy for myself, sort of a nosql data base à la Json.

**Current setup is something like this example:**

```
{
    "Cities": [

        {
            "name": "Seattle",
            "shops": [
                "Walmart",
                "Coles",
                "Batmans Protein shop"
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "Los angeles",
            "shops": [
                "Walmart",
                "Costco"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "shops": [{
        "name": "Walmart",
        "departments": [
            "Meat",
            "Vegetables"
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Coles",
        "departments": [
            "Meat",
            "Vegetables"
        ]
    }]
}
```

The problem occurs when I ie. want to display Cities that has shops with vegetable sections. There would be an awful amount of parsing before being able to show the result.

**So I am considering the following alternatives:**

1. Keeping the data normalized but merge it client side upon page load to lower data being sent.
2. Merge it when it's generated which means that the objects will be much larger, but less client site operations.

**Things to consider:**

- The application would be internal in 99% of the cases which more or less makes bandwidth a non-issue.
- I would like to avoid using a database, because that would mean that it'd be harder to people to implement my solution.
- If I "merge" the data an estimation of the total would be 20MB Json data.
- The current version uses a pre-generated html page of 12+MB AND the 5MB Json which takes ages to render, so it can only get better. :)

Again, very general and any advice would be appreciated.

/Patrik

Answer (score 1):

I was also in same situation few months back, i opted point 1. Keeping the data normalized but merge it client side upon page load to lower data being sent.

These days web client are more powerful, server has a limit of Ram and CPU, so we should make use of client's computer power also.

Further, You can make use of JS WebWorker to distribute the computing in number of threads, to make the computation or merging faster.

Good Luck.

Comment: Good suggestion Sachin!

Comment: I tested it, and that turned out to be a bad idea. Took way too long with the amount of data I have. Thanks for the suggestion though!